# creating custom MIME type in cq5/AEM

Tags: mime-types, aem

I need to add support for a proprietary 3D format in cq5/AEM. Despite having absolutely no experience with this, I managed to generate a few working components to visualize the assets.

But now, I need to create custom media handler to generate renditions and thumbnails from the model. The problem is, media handlers can only work on assets of specific MIME types, and cq5 do not associate a type to my assets. Thus, I can not have a media handler called on them.

Is there any way to customize how cq5 associate MIME types to an asset, or I is there another way to circumvent the problem?

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: No, I could not do that. Maybe you can find something if you find a way to change the Sling configuration at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found what I needed. You can link MIME type to extensions by going to the OSGI console  at `http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr` and to the `Apache Sling MIME type Service` configuration. There, you can add new MIME / extension link:

```
MIME extensions...
model/collada+xml dae
```

Comment: Can you tell me a generic mime Type. Like I am trying to upload DAM Asset using OSGi Bundle(Programmaically). It could be a PDF, doc,xls can you tell me a generic Mime Type