# Define custom mime type in cq5/AEM

Tags: adobe, mime-types

I want to define custom mime type in crx/de but I don't know how to do it.
I have found one link of stackoverflow but still I am not getting the clear idea to define the custom mime type in crx/de can anyone please help me with documentation or steps to do it which would be really help-full for me.
Thanks in Advance

Link of stackoverflow which I have refered
[creating custom MIME type in cq5/AEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659418/creating-custom-mime-type-in-cq5-aem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely suggest you read [Configuring OSGi](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/configuring-osgi.html) in the Adobe documentation.

Assuming you have an AEM instance running on your local machine on port 4502, you can follow this link into the Apache Felix console to configure the "The Apache Sling MIME Type Service" at http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl. In the dialog, click on any of the plus symbols. Add your mime type, followed by a space and then the file extension to affiliate the mime type. For example: `application/json json`.

If you want to create an OSGi config in CRXDE|Lite, you can create a node named `org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl` of type `sling:OsgiConfig` under `/apps/<yourProject/config`. Create a property called `mime.types` which is a multi-valued String. Add your mime type and extension as described above. Yogesh Upadhyay has a detailed explanation with screenshots here: http://www.wemblog.com/2012/10/how-to-work-with-configurations-in-cq.html.

Updating a configuration in the web console or CRXDE|Lite is fine for testing but is not maintainable. You can store an OSGi configuration in your Source Control Management system by creating the following file: `/apps/<yourProject>/config/org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    mime.types="[video/x-matroska mkv, video/dvd vob, mymime/type extension]"
/>
```

By storing your configuration in your source control repository you get the obvious benefit of versioning. Just as important, however, every time you build your code to a new or existing AEM instance, the config file will update the service. Read the documentation and it will describe how you can have different configurations for different Sling run modes as such that you have different settings for your development versus stage and production AEM instances.

Comment: Thanks for help @nateyolles